# jeditable table cell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jeditable

I am having an issue when using jeditable to edit a cell in a table.

The project is the MVC 2 web application and the table has been put on the standard about page.
How do i tell the script to call a specific method in the controller ? because it is currently just loading the entire page into the cell.

This is the javascript:

$(document).ready(function () {

              $('.editable').editable('http://localhost:2196/Home/About', {
                  type: 'text',
                  cancel: 'Cancel',
                  event: 'dblclick',
                  submit: 'OK',
                  tooltip: 'double Click to edit...'
              });
          });

This is the table :

```
        <% foreach (DataTableEditable.Models.Company item in (IEnumerable<DataTableEditable.Models.Company>)Model)
        {%>
            <tr id="<%= Html.Encode(item.ID) %>">
                <td  class="editable"><%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %> </td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Address) %> </td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Town) %> </td>
            </tr>
         <%  }%>
```

Thanks lots
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks but I have now solved it.

I needed to add

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult UpdateSettings(string id, string value)
    { 
        return Content(value);
    }
```

to the controller.